# What could cause conflict with Tipsy's focus trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tipsy

I'm using the Tipsy jquery plugin and the focus triggers acts the same way as the hover trigger. Tipsy stops displaying once my mouse is off an input field even though the field is still focused. What could cause this issue? Based on this [jQuery tipsy plugin. On focus trigger not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258519/jquery-tipsy-plugin-on-focus-trigger-not-working). It's not the actual plugin that's causing the issue

Here's the page I'm testing it on

http://uploads.glumbo.com/?op=registration

Comment: Code.... Coooooode.... COoOoOoOoOoODE!!!! Or at least a jFiddle demonstrating.

Comment: I'm trying it on http://uploads.glumbo.com/?op=registration

Comment: Your link doesn't work! And please don't share files with us on an upload site. The preferred method is using http://jsfiddle.net/ and next after that use dropbox (http://www.dropbox.com).

Comment: @fudgey that's clearly the site he's working on. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to update Tipsy file you are using. [The one you are using](http://uploads.glumbo.com/js/jquery.tipsy.js) right now is significantly different than [the latest version of Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js).

Comment: +1 good point :) and DUH, I did all that work and I think all he wants is just the focus to work LOL.

Answer (score 1):

As Haochi says, you need to update your Tipsy version to [1.0.0a](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy). Then use the following code to add both hover and focus to your tipsy tooltips ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fpfCB/34/)):

```
$('.registerform [title]')
    .tipsy({
        trigger: 'manual', // manual stops binding of any internal tipsy events
        gravity: 'w',
        fade: true
    })
    .bind('focus mouseenter', function(e) {
        // flag indicating the input has focus
        if (e.type === 'focus') {
            $(this).addClass('hasFocus');
        }
        $(this).tipsy("show");
    })
    .bind('blur mouseleave', function(e) {
        // if mouseleave is triggered but the input has focus, ignore it
        if (!$(this).is('.hasFocus') || e.type === 'blur') {
            $(this).removeClass('hasFocus').tipsy("hide");
        }
    });
```

Comment: `Tipsy` isn't working in the demo link you've provided.

Comment: @MohitBhansali it's because the demo is linked to a github raw file, which doesn't work any more. Try [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fpfCB/103/)